# Bash: editing code format in visual studio code

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

Dealing with the followin function of CSV processing in bash:

```
  sort_data () {
       for csv in "${rescore}"/${str_name}/*.csv; do
        csv_name=$(basename "$csv" .csv)
        if [ "${MY_SORT_METHOD}" = "2" ]; then 
         LC_ALL=C sort -k2,2g ${csv} > "${rescore}"/${str_name}/${csv_name}_std.csv
        # run awk script to take 5% of data
    awk -v lines="$(wc -l < "${rescore}"/${str_name}/${csv_name}_std.csv)" '
    BEGIN{
      top=int(lines/20)
    }
    FNR>(top){exit}
    1
    ' "${rescore}"/${str_name}/${csv_name}_std.csv >> "${rescore}"/${str_name}/${csv_name}_TOP.csv
    # remove input csv with all lines
    rm "${rescore}"/${str_name}/${csv_name}_std.csv
        else
        echo "Debug: data was not sorted correctly!"
        fi
        rm $csv
       done
    }
```

I am looking for the possibility to fix the representation of AWK part of the function, which should be inside of the provided IF condition (vizually like in python!) Is it possible using Visual Code Studio to select a part of the code and shift this part entirely on the rignt on the selected numbers of tabs?

Comment: On Windows VS it is a case of selecting the block and hitting {tab} the necessary number of times (once per indent required). Does that not work?

Comment: Why are you only double-quoting the `$rescore` variable?  You should be quoting all of them.  e.g. don't do `"${rescore}"/${str_name}/${csv_name}_std.csv`.  Instead do: `"${rescore}/${str_name}/${csv_name}_std.csv"`.    and you should definitely be quoting `$csv` in the `rm $csv` line.    Double-quote variables every time, except when you explicitly **want** shell word-splitting to occur (and even then, you should consider using an array instead).